# Excel : Finding min/max of N number of previous entries

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Say I have a set of numerical data, A1 to A100.

If in D5 I would like to find the min of the last **5** values in A1:A100, the formula I used is `=min(A1:A5)`So in D6 this would be `=min(A2:A6)`, etc.

If in B1 I wanted to input an integer that controlled the range of last **N** values, such that if N=3 then D5 would be `=min(A3:A5)` and D6 is `=min(A4:A6)`

How can I form a general formula in D5 that takes into account **N**(variable) number of previous terms in A1:A100, where **N** is my input in B1 (I want to be able to change this) ?

I don't really have a clue on how to go about with this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to define a range based on variables, like what cell you're in and a calculated starting point.  You can use the INDIRECT function to do that.  INDIRECT creates an actual cell or range reference from a string that you build and/or calculate.  Cell D5 would contain:

```
=MIN(INDIRECT("A" & ROW()-$B$1+1 & ":A" & ROW(),1))
```

(Some spaces added for readability).  You can copy or drag that down the page as needed.

- This uses the ROW() function to get the row of the current cell.
- $B$1 is your reference to the cell containing the size of the range (the $'s lock the cell reference so it doesn't change when you copy the formula).
- The +1 adjusts from a range size to the starting row number.
- The &'s concatenate the pieces of the string
- The last 1 is optional in Excel (required in LO Calc, which is what I used to verify the formula).  It identifies the style of cell addressing used in the formula.

More detail on the INDIRECT function can be found [***here***](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

I populated some easy to verify numbers in column A, and the result looks like this:

[image: MIN example]

If you change the function from MIN to MAX, you get this:

[image: MAX example]

Answer (score 0):

Can this solution be turned into an array formula so that the formula extends down column D automatically as more data is entered in column A?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1155083)

Comment: Thank you Rohit, I will do.